# jqGrid 4.10 autocomplete doesn't complete all fields + inline editing focus is not changing to a new row

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

Firstly: I have the following column with autocomplete:

```
{name:'ISRC',index:'isrc.ISRC', width:100,align:"left",editable:true,
    edittype:'text',
    editoptions:{
        dataInit:function (elem) {
            var sel_row_id = $grid.jqGrid ('getGridParam', 'selrow');
            if (sel_row_id === undefined || sel_row_id === null) {sel_row_id="jqg1";}

            $(elem).autocomplete({
                source: "xtras/search_isrc.php",
                dataType: "json",
                minLength: 2,
                select: function(event, ui) {
                    console.log("EditOptions - "+sel_row_id);
//                              $("#"+sel_row_id+"_id").val(ui.item ? ui.item.isrc_ID : "");
                    $("#"+sel_row_id+"_ISRC").val(ui.item.ISRC);
                    $("#"+sel_row_id+"_Track_Name").val(ui.item.Track_Name);
                    $("#"+sel_row_id+"_Track_Time").val(ui.item.Track_Time);
                    $("#"+sel_row_id+"_ArtistName").val(ui.item.ArtistName);
                    $("#"+sel_row_id+"_Writer").val(ui.item.Writer);
                    $("#"+sel_row_id+"_Publisher").val(ui.item.Publisher);
                    $("#"+sel_row_id+"_TrackPLineYear").val(ui.item.TrackPLineYear);
                    $("#"+sel_row_id+"_TrackPLineInfo").val(ui.item.TrackPLineInfo);
                    $("#"+sel_row_id+"_isrc_id").val(ui.item.isrc_ID);
                    var ffs = ui.item.isrc_ID;
                    console.log("ffs - "+ffs);
                },
                change: function(event, ui) {
                    if (ui.item) {
                        $("#"+sel_row_id+"_ISRC").val(ui.item.ISRC);
                        $("#"+sel_row_id+"_Track_Name").val(ui.item.Track_Name);
                        $("#"+sel_row_id+"_Track_Time").val(ui.item.Track_Time);
                        $("#"+sel_row_id+"_ArtistName").val(ui.item.ArtistName);
                        $("#"+sel_row_id+"_Writer").val(ui.item.Writer);
                        $("#"+sel_row_id+"_Publisher").val(ui.item.Publisher);
                        $("#"+sel_row_id+"_TrackPLineYear").val(ui.item.TrackPLineYear);
                        $("#"+sel_row_id+"_TrackPLineInfo").val(ui.item.TrackPLineInfo);
                        $("#"+sel_row_id+"_isrc_id").val(ui.item.isrc_ID);
                    }
                }
            });
            $('.ui-autocomplete').css('zIndex',1000); // if autocomplete has misalignment so we are manually setting it 

            if(sel_row_id != 'jqg1'){
                $(elem).css({'border':'1px solid red','background-color':'#e8b7cf'});
            }
        }
    }
},
...
{name:'isrc_ID',index:'isrc.isrc_ID', hidden:true, width:50, sortable:true, editable:true},
```

`ffs` puts in console correct id
I also have inline editing set on doubleClick:

```
ondblClickRow: function (rowid) {
    console.log('ondblClickRow - '+rowid);

    var savedRows = $grid.jqGrid("getGridParam", "savedRow");
    $grid.jqGrid("setSelection", rowid);

    if (savedRows.length > 0 && savedRows[0].id !== rowid) {
        // cancel editing of another row is editing
        // don't cancel on double click on the current editing
        $grid.jqGrid("restoreRow", savedRows[0].id);
    }
    if (savedRows.length === 0) {
        $grid.jqGrid("editRow", rowid, editOptions);
    } 
}
```

I only was able to make autocomplete work after I forced the row selection on this line `$grid.jqGrid("setSelection", rowid);`

The autocomplete PHP:

```
$sql = "select * from isrc where Track_Name REGEXP '[[:<:]]($q)[[:alnum:]]' or ISRC REGEXP '[[:<:]]($q)[[:alnum:]]' GROUP BY ISRC;"; 
$rsd = mysqli_query($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"], $sql); 
while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($rsd)) { 

    $row_array['value'] = $data['ISRC']; 
    $row_array['label'] = $data['ISRC'].' - '.$data['Track_Name'].' - '.$data['ArtistName'].' - '.$data['Track_Time'].' - '.$data['TrackPLineInfo'];

    $row_array['ISRC'] = $data['ISRC'];   
    $row_array['Track_Name'] = $data['Track_Name'];
    $row_array['ArtistName'] = $data['ArtistName']; 
    $row_array['Track_Time'] = $data['Track_Time'];
    $row_array['Writer'] = $data['Writer']; 
    $row_array['Publisher'] = $data['Publisher']; 
    $row_array['TrackPLineYear'] = $data['TrackPLineYear']; 
    $row_array['TrackPLineInfo'] = $data['TrackPLineInfo']; 
    $row_array['isrc_ID'] = $data['isrc_ID'];   

} 

((is_null($___mysqli_res = mysqli_close($conn))) ? false : $___mysqli_res); 

echo json_encode($row_array);
```

On Select autocomplete looks exactly as expected (all fields filled in correctly)
After submitting to server to add into database I get this:

```
_REQUEST - 2015-12-02 17:00:13: 
Array
(
    [Catalogue] => 1958
    [ISRC] => GBCQV0200199
    [Disc_Number] => 1
    [Track_Number] => 4
    [is_bonus] => No
    [Track_Name] => Hitch Hiking Woman
    [ArtistName] => Peter Green Splinter Group
    [Track_Time] => 00:00:00
    [Writer] => Turner
    [Publisher] => Bug Music Ltd
    [TrackPLineYear] => 1997
    [TrackPLineInfo] => Snapper Music
    [isrc_ID] => 
    [id] => jqg1
    [copyID] => 
    [oper] => add
)
```

as you can see `[isrc_ID] =>`is blank. The only explanation I can think of - it is because this field is hidden.... 
How do I fix this?

Secondly: jqGrid - on add - if before pressing **+** to add a line I had any other existing row selected/clicked on - the grid thinks I'm editing the new row `[id] => jqg1` instead of adding. Here are my definitions:

```
var editOptions = {
            keys: true,
            aftersavefunc: function() {
                var $self = $(this);
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $self.trigger("reloadGrid", [{current: true}]);
                }, 50);
            },
            url: "xtras/Records.php"
        },
        gridIdSelector = "#Records",
        pagerIdSelector = "#Records_pager",
        $grid = $(gridIdSelector);
```

and a pager initiation:

```
.jqGrid("navGrid", pagerIdSelector, {add: false, edit: false, refreshstate: "current"})
        .jqGrid("inlineNav", pagerIdSelector, { editParams: editOptions, addParams: {addRowParams: editOptions}})
        .jqGrid("navButtonAdd", pagerIdSelector, {
            caption: "",
            title: "Copy selected row",
            id: $grid[0].id + "_ilcopy", 
            buttonicon: "ui-icon-copy",
            onClickButton: function () {
                var $self = $(this), p = $self.jqGrid("getGridParam"), rowData,
                    srcrowid = p.selrow, savedRows = p.savedRow;

                if (srcrowid !== null) {
                    if (savedRows.length > 0) {
                        // cancel editing
                        $self.jqGrid("restoreRow", savedRows[0].id);
                    }
                    rowData = $self.jqGrid("getRowData", srcrowid);
                    rowData.id = "";
                    rowData.Catalogue = "";
                    rowData.copyID = srcrowid;
                    $self.jqGrid("addRow", {
                        initdata: rowData,
                        addRowParams: editOptions 
                    });
                } else {
                    alert("Please select a row to copy");
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
```

How do I make sure that on inline edit the previous selection is completely reset?

Sorry I've ran out of ideas why both of these behaviours. If you think you need to see more code - please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that I full understand the problem, which you describe with Autocomplete, but I suppose you want that the row will be **not deselected** if it was previously selected. It's behavior of old jqGrid. You can just add the option

```
singleSelectClickMode: "selectonly"
```

which restore the old selection behavior.

I could see some other problems in your code. Free jqGrid have implemented extension to `dataInit` callback. It has the second parameter `options` which has the following helpful properties:

- `rowId` with the value like `"70"`
- `name` with the column name as the value, for example `"invdate"`
- `id` with the value like `"70_invdate"`
- `mode` with the value like `"edit"` or `"add"`

Moreover the DOM element `elem` is already placed on the page and you can use something like `$(elem).closets("tr.jqgrow").attr("id")` to get the rowid. It's better to use `options.rowId` of cause as the expression `$(elem).closets("tr.jqgrow").attr("id")`.

Thus I recommend you to change the beginning of the code

```
dataInit:function (elem) {
    var sel_row_id = $grid.jqGrid ('getGridParam', 'selrow');
    if (sel_row_id === undefined || sel_row_id === null) {sel_row_id="jqg1";}
    ...
}
```

to

```
dataInit: function (elem, options) {
```

and to use `options.rowId` instead of `sel_row_id` below. I have to stress that the assigning `sel_row_id="jqg1"` is wrong. It could work correctly at the adding of the first row, but it will be definitively wrong in case of adding next rows.

At the end of the code of `dataInit` I recommend you to replace

```
if(sel_row_id != 'jqg1'){
```

to

```
if (options.mode !== "add") {
```

**UPDATED**: I suppose that you need to use `editable: "hidden"` property instead of `editable: true` for `isrc_ID`. You need to change

```
$("#" + options.rowId + "_isrc_id").val(ui.item.isrc_ID);
```

to

```
$grid.jqGrid("setCell", options.rowId, "isrc_ID", ui.item.isrc_ID)
```

because the usage of `editable: true` for **hidden** field don't creates any hidden `<input>` element.

I introduced the option `editable: "hidden"` property to provide simple way to send any additional column to the server which is not editable. It's important to mention that the feature `editable: "hidden"` *for inline and cell editing* is implemented only in 4.11.0 version of jqGrid. I recommend you to load the current source from GitHub which is identical to 4.11.0, but which contains one important fix additionally. I'll publish 4.11.1 at the end of the week.

Comment: hi agian! ok understood and changed. but why `$("#"+sel_row_id+"_isrc_id").val(ui.item.isrc_ID);` is not filled in with the value which is sent from `source: "xtras/search_isrc.php"`? how do I fix that?

Comment: @Elen: I don't full understand your scenario. Typically one can easy answer on such question having working the demo, which can be debugged. I even not sure why you use both `select` and `change` callbacks, which test case exactly you use, which jQuery UI version you use, how `ui.item` looks like, has it all the properties or not, ... I wrote you that the usage of `sel_row_id` in Autocomplete is unsafe. Do you changed it to `options.rowId`? ...

Comment: yes i did change to `options.rowId` it still doesn't work. Dont worry about `change` at the moment. I used to use it for both add and edit, but can probably omit it now. Not sure yet.

Comment: The ui.item looks like this after select:`Object {value: "GBCQV0200302", label: "GBCQV0200302 - Cyphered - Asgaroth - 00:02:29 - Peaceville Records Ltd", ISRC: "GBCQV0200302", Track_Name: "Cyphered", ArtistName: "Asgaroth"…}
ArtistName: "Asgaroth"
ISRC: "GBCQV0200302"
Publisher: ""
TrackPLineInfo: "Peaceville Records Ltd"
TrackPLineYear: "2002"
Track_Name: "Cyphered"
Track_Time: "00:02:29"
Writer: ""
isrc_ID: "535"
label: "GBCQV0200302 - Cyphered - Asgaroth - 00:02:29 - Peaceville Records Ltd"
value: "GBCQV0200302"
__proto__: Object`

Comment: - as you can see `isrc_ID: "535"` - does exist. but not passed to server when i press enter to accept a new record (I put a dump of my `$_REQUEST` var in my question. I will try to make a fiddle... but i always have problem with how to go about ajax as the website i'm working on is internal only...

Comment: @Elen: Sorry, but you wrote now "as you can see isrc_ID: "535" - does exist. but not passed to server when i press enter". The code don't send anything to the server. The question is: will be the input field `isrc_ID` changed to `535` or not? **I suppose that you need to use `editable: "hidden"` property instead of `editable: true` for `isrc_ID` and to change `$("#" + options.rowId + "_isrc_id").val(ui.item.isrc_ID);` to `$grid.jqGrid("setCell", options.rowId, "isrc_ID", ui.item.isrc_ID)`**

Comment: @Elen: See **UPDATED** part of my answer. You need to get the latest free jqGrid sources from the GitHub.

Comment: As I suspected! But couldn't work around. I will wait for 4.11 version and amend code as you suggested. Will update you then. Thanks,

Comment: @Elen: What problem you have now? What is not work? The version 4.11 is already published last week, I will publish 4.11.1 which have one line more. If no other bugs will be reported in the next two days that the only changes in 4.11.1 compared with the version which you get now from GitHub will be in the comment. I recommend you just modify the code to use `https//rawgit.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/master/css/ui.jqgrid.css` and `https://rawgit.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/master/js/jquery.jqgrid.src.js` (see [the wiki](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs)).

Comment: @Elen: I have published [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) v4.11.1 just now.

Comment: Hi Oleg, sorry i was very busy at work. I have published my grid online now - http://takt.vacau.com/records/records.html - i have updated the code as per your suggestions. The problem i have now - on select of autocomplete value - grid loses focus (ideally it should jump to the next cell - `Disc_Number`). Also dblClick one row, then dblClick another row - `Catalogue` value (which is select) disappears.. And despite `multipleSearch:true` i don't have multiple options for search...

Comment: @Elen: You fill the grid using the data like `"cell": ["VILE27TCD", "GBCQV0100373", "1", "8", "0", "Weltschmerz", "Diablerie", "00:06:03", "Ahokas, Lunden, Ruokola, Suorsa, Tukiainen, Villberg", "Teosto", "2001", "Peaceville Records Ltd", "20863", "23368"]`. It means that the usage of `formatter:'select'` is wrong. See [the old documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:predefined_formatter#formatter_type_select). You should remove the property.

Comment: @Elen: The options of `navGrid` are: `.jqGrid('navGrid','#gridpager',{parameters},prmEdit, prmAdd, prmDel, prmSearch, prmView);` Thus you use `{}` as searching options and `{multipleSearch:true, sopt:['eq','ne','cn','bw','bn','ge','le','lt','gt'], showQuery: false}` as View options. I recommend you to use `searching` and `navOptions` option of jqGrid which allows to specify searching options and `navGrid` options. Then you can use `navGrid` without any additional parameters. See [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/New-style-of-usage-options-of-internal-methods).

Comment: Hi Oleg i deliberately added this property `formatter:'select'` - as without it select on edit does not work. See updated -  takt.vacau.com/records/records.html - try to inline edit and try to select a different catalogue

Comment: re Search - so... now i have to specify search option for every field i want to be able to search by - `{ name: "catalogue", ..., searchoptions: { sopt: ["eq", "ne", ...] } }`? can i not specify this for all fields globally?

Comment: And the article doesn't explain how to use multisearch in the new grid... I changed code to `$("#Records").jqGrid("navGrid", pagerIdSelector,
  {edit: false, add: false, del: true, refreshstate: "current"},
  {},{},{},
  {multipleSearch:true, sopt:['eq','ne','cn','bw','bn','ge','le','lt','gt'], showQuery: false},
  {}
 )` - multisearch still not enabled..

Comment: @Elen: I wanted to stop the discussion already multiple times. Stackoverfow is not a help forum where you get for free the answers on all the problems which you get in your project. At least *you have to divide the problems, which you have, in separate question, which you post on stackoverflow*. You should formulate the questions so that there have some value for other people and not only for you. *No commutative questions* should be posted. You accept questions after you get *the answer on the posted question*. Nobody want to have "never ending Story" in comments to some old question.

Comment: @Elen: You even not voted the answer to mark it helpful in some way and continue to post more and more new questions in the comment. Sorry, but you should hold the main rules of stackoverflow.

Comment: sorry - you are right. My bad. shall i delete all irrelevant comments to the original question including this one?

Comment: @Elen: Deleting of old comment is unneeded. You should just try to formulate divide your current problems and to post with related code fragment in separate questions. Please try to thing about other readers of your question. Only clear separate questions can be good indexed and be found by other people who could have the same problems.